# Checking Model property in View not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using a custom popup editor template for Kendo grid and am having issues checking the property of my Model.

I have the following code in my editor template:

```
<div>
    @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.ActionID)
    @Model.ActionID
    @if (Model.ActionID > 0)
    {
        <p>True</p>
        @Model.ActionID
    }
    else
    {
        <p>False</p>
        @Model.ActionID
    }
</div>
```

The Kendo TextBoxFor properly displays the appropriate ActionID, but the @Model.ActionID and the @if statement are always turning up as 0 causing the conditional statement to be False.

I have had success checking Model properties like this previously and I am not sure if this is because it's a custom editor template for the grid or what.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the controller where the page gets loaded; HttpGet. Then check what is getting passed back to the view.

Comment: If the code is always rendering false, that means your `ActionID` property value is `0`. Check the code where you set it.

Comment: My confusion is that the Model is properly loaded which is evident based on the fact that the TextBoxFor is displaying the ActionID as expected

Comment: Try removing the line "@Model.ActionID" between the TexBoxFor and the if statement. That's the only thing that looks odd to me at this point.

Comment: @580 Removing it doesn't change anything.  I only put it there to begin with just to display the value for troubleshooting purposes.  Same with the other two inside the if statement.

Comment: What does it display after the TextBoxFor line?

Comment: @580 It displays 0

Comment: @Shyju I considered that, but the TextBoxFor is checking the same property and it displays the appropriate value

Comment: Can you add a little bit more such as how the model is declared and maybe the controller method responsible for passing the view down?

Comment: You need to give more context (what you claiming is not possible unless you the value is being used from `ModelState`)

Comment: It sounds like the `ActionID` getter is unexpectedly setting the value to `0`, but returning the previous value after having done so. Need to see how the model is implemented to know more.

Comment: Alternatively, Kendo could be setting it to `0`, although that seems unlikely...

Comment: No, you can't do that in an editor template - see [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/editor-template-if-statements). Editor templates are built when the grid is rendered and then it uses [MVVM binding](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview#bind-the-view-to-the-view-model).